# group all radio buttons with different names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find a way to validate all of my radio buttons to make sure atleast one of them is checked. The problem is doing it with the names and id's have to remain in the format that they are in. 
So basically I want to have a way to group all of my radio buttons even with different names and id's.

I understad how to loop for all checked buttons in the table but some are outside of the table, the code is just an example of what I need to do.

```
  <table id="table" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="blue" id="blue" value="blue1" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="blue" id="blue" value="blue2" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="red" id="red" value="red1" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="red" id="red" value="red2" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="blue" id="green" value="green1" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="green" id="green" value="green2" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you add class names, or another attribute, to associate the related inputs together? Incidentally a duplicate `id`  immediately invalidates your html, and creates problems with/for JavaScript. Whether they can or cannot be changed by you, they ***must*** be changed.

Comment: Do you want to get all radio inputs of the page? PS: You should use unique ids (*identifiers*).

Comment: I think I can add a class to the ones i need and do a jquery select for that class. But I think by adding the class if I checked one, it would check the rest in that class.

Comment: Well the page is not done by me, but I agree with the unique ID's this is in the scenario I cant change them.

Comment: @user2168066 If I were you I'd go back to the person who told you to do this, and who wrote the initial page and tell them that what they're doing is wrong and you **have** to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0){
   //at least one radio on your page is checked
}
```

Comment: I have thought about this, but there is one radio at the top of the page that must be selected. the other 30 have to have atleast one of them selected.

Comment: Well.... at the same time I guess that means I could just check to make sure that atleast 2 of them are selected

Comment: @user2168066 is there any unique identifier on that one radio button at the top?

Comment: @user2168066: If so use `if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 1)`

Comment: Or $('input[type="radio"]:not(:first):checked').length for exemple or again $('input[type="radio"]').not(":first").filter(":checked").length etc ....

Comment: Ok so the solution would be to check for my top button to be true, and for the checked.length > 1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are going for the HTML5 validation, just make one of them required, and then change it as they go:

```
<input required type="radio" name="blue" id="blue" value="blue1" />
```

JS:

```
$radios = $('input[type="radio"]');
$radios.on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $radios.prop('required', false);
        $(this).prop('required', true);
    }
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Must check at least one radio");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your posted html I'd suggest changing the `name` of all those posted `<input />` elements to `colour` (or `color`, according to language preference) to clearly associate them together.

However, if that can't be done, and you're able to add a class-name as a means of associating the group:

```
var allInputs = $('input.colour'),
       checked = allInputs.filter(':checked'),
      choiceMade = checked.length > 0;
```

Incidentally:

> …I think by adding the class if I checked one, it would check the rest in that class.

No, that behaviour - unchecking one element should another be checked - is entirely dependent on the `<input />` sharing a `name` attribute and being semantically grouped. It doesn't matter how else you create an association, so long as you don't yourself create that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure at least one radio button within table is checked and the one at the top of the page:

```
if ($('#top-radio').is(':checked') && $('#table :radio:checked').length) {
    // valid, something is checked
}
```